# integrating web app with ios google maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, web-applications, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am not a programmer, but I have an application I have a group of developers working on. I would like to better describe what I would like my developers to do, but I don't know what is required to accomplish what I am going for.

I have a web application that is intended to run from a tablet, most likely an iPad. A large component of the system is a courier type routing system that optimizes a list of addresses. There is an embedded map in the application (using cloudmade), but it is for viewing and does not provide detail. At this point I have determined the best approach would be to provide a map link for each address that opens the native mapping application on the device to provide turn by turn and voice nav. I have used (and personally do not like) Maps on iOS compared to Google Maps for iOS. I would like the default map application to be a setting inside my application that allows the user to select Maps or Google Maps as their default mapping application.

First, based on my basic description, does anyone have any suggestions on a better approach? Second, what do my developers need to make the default maps app Google Maps through a web app on iOS?

Comment: your question is so general, and has no code specifications. please try to be more consist, or let one of your developers asks in some kind of programming way!

Answer (score 1):

If your web app links to http://maps.apple.com, then it will open the Apple maps, if it links to comgooglemaps://, then it will open the Google maps (if the Google maps app is installed).

Documentation on the Apple maps URL scheme is here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

And the Google maps URL scheme is here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

So, the setting in your web app which changes which map app to use would just need to change the format of the map URLs which it generates.